# Make passed Android Tests visible in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio (0.8.9) and have several unit tests. When I run them with an *Android Test* Run Configuration they only show up in the test report window if the test fails.

I'd also like to see them when they pass. (It makes me happy :-) Is it possible to configure this somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you upgrade to 0.8.13 there is a toggle in the output window that lets you hide/show passed tests

[image: Show or Hide Passed Unit Tests]

Answer (score 2):

On newer AndroidStudio version, toggle the "tick" icon will show/hide passed test

[image]